# Vectorize a call to a subroutine

Tags: performance, optimization, fortran, vectorization, fortran90

I have a program where the call to subroutine `foo` doesn't get vectorized even though `IVDEP` pragma is used.
`vec-report3` doesn't give me any reason on why the call is not vectorized. Is it because of memory reference?

Note: arr1, arr2, arr3 are all defined in a common block

```
program test
    integer i, j, k, n
    double precision arr1(5, 5, n, n), aar2(5, 5, n, n), aar3(5, n, n, n)
    !DIR$ IVDEP
    do i=1, n
        call foo(arr1(1, 1, i, k), aar2(1, 1, i, k), aar3(1, i, j, k))
    enddo
end

subroutine foo( fooarr1, fooarr2, fooarr3 )
    implicit none
    double precision fooarr1(5, 5), fooarr2(5, 5), fooarr3(5)
    some computations on fooarr1, fooarr2, fooarr3
    fooarr1,fooarr2,fooarr3 gets updated. But there are no vector dependance

return
end
```

Comment: Why not move the loop inside `foo` and try to vectorise it.

Comment: @HristoIliev: That is a good suggestion. I'll try it

Comment: @HristoIliev: It did vectorize after I moved the loop inside `foo`. 
I'm looking for other options. Will making this subroutine `foo` elemental vectorize the function call?

Comment: You cannot vectorise function calls. Vectorisation is only possible if the function could be inlined, either by hand or automatically by the compiler.

Comment: ok. I thought that elemental functions can be vectorized.

Comment: May be you are confusing two meanings of _vectorise_ here. One kind of vectorisation is calling a function in a vector context, e.g. `func(x)` where `x` is an array and `func()` gets called for each element of `x`. This could be performed in parallel, e.g. within automatically generated OpenMP parallel regions. The other kind of vectorisation is doing loops with vector instructions so that more elements could be handled at once. These are two completely different things.

Comment: in your example `func()` is an elemental function, right? So when I invoke `func(x)`, where `x` is a vector, the calls to `func()` for each scalar element of `x` can be done in parallel. So you mean to say that this is parallelization and not vectorization?

Comment: Elemental subroutines have no side effects and operate only on the given scalar argument. Thus they can be applied to all elements of an array in any order and even concurrently (in parallel). Vectorisation in this case means that you can call them in a vector context instead of running a `DO` or `FORALL` loop. This is not to be confused with hardware vectorisation. Some _intrinsic_ elemental functions like `SQRT` can also be vectorised in hardware, e.g. compiled to the `SQRTPD` SSE instruction or to the `VSQRTPD` AVX instruction.

Comment: @AstroCB Why exactly do you capitalize `i` in old code samples?

Comment: @VladimirF Sorry; that was a script bug. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It can not be simply done, if the subroutine is not trivial and is not inlined. Vectorisation is usage of a limited set of SIMD instructions (Are you on a vector Cray or NEC, or on x86?), where you can for example make four multiplications simultanously. But for simultanous execution of procedures you should be probably heading for parallelization using threads or you should search potential for vectorization inside the subroutine.

--edit--
 When I checked the web references, compiler vendors indeed always have examples like

```
!DIR$ IVDEP
      DO I = 1,N
         A(I) = A(I+1) + 3.0
      END DO
```

so there are no calls inside, just a simple computation. To be sure what is going on you should also post the code of your subroutine.

Comment: I'm on x86. The subroutine has more than 50 LOC and I din't want to inline it. This snippet is part of a MPI program and it is already parallelized.

Comment: fooarr1,fooarr2,fooarr3 gets updated inside the subroutine which reflects on the original arrays arr1,arr2,arr3. But there are no vector dependance

Comment: Then it can not be vectorized. You could find places for vectorization inside of it or use threads. It doesn't matter there is no dependence, vectorization is for simple loops using special CPU instructions.

Comment: Also what is the prurpose of the return before the end of your subroutine? It is redundant.

Comment: Is having `return;end subroutine` considered bad style in Fortran?  I often write it in out of habit, but I suppose I can work on breaking the habit if Fortran programmers consider that bad style.

Comment: It is the same as having `STOP` before end program. I do not see any reason for that in modern code.  I consider it being a reminiscence of  a pretty old style. It was probably necessary in FORTRAN 66 (if I read the standard correctly).

Comment: @VladimirF: This code was written in the 90s. That might be the reason.

Comment: @VladimirF: you can also vectorize subroutine calls inside loops.

Comment: Maybe in some special cases, where the compiler is able to inline it. Give us an example.